# How to produce an Accurate clock face with Roman Numerals

Tags: fonts, typography, formatting

As a personal art project I would like to create a large physical clock face.

I am not employing any software.

I wish to use paper, pencil, ruler, compass, protractor etc..

I wish to know how to place Roman Numerals around the clock circumference to denote the hours. How should I position the numerals so that they take into account the curvature of the clock and the fact that "I" takes up so much less space than "VIII"?

The base of each roman numeral will be facing the centre of the clock. e.g the number VI (6) will be upside down.

What I am concerned about is that each hours numerals do not appear distorted.

For example in the extreme case; if each hours numerals base reached the centre of the clock and the top (or head) of the numerals reached to the outer rim of the clock face the numerals would be distorted. They would have to fit in a wedge shape where their base was zero units wide and their head resides around 1/12 of the circumference of the clock face.

this is what I want to avoid as much as possible.

Also the twelve digits take up a different amount of space

I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, XI, & XII

e.g. I is roughly 50% of II, 33% of III, 25% of VIII

I wish to employ mathematics to place the numerals
I do not wish to use "contrast and compare" to other examples.

Comment: Have you seen an analog clock before? It's always the same position for the numbers no matter what the font used. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: I would think you should put the numerals at the 1 o'clock, 2 o'clock, 3 o'clock, etc. positions...

Comment: [Google has examples you know](https://www.google.com/search?q=roman+numeral+clock%5C&num=20&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQsdWmqYzbAhVKWH0KHe2xCF8Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1396&bih=667&dpr=1.38)

Comment: "...as accurate as possible." - accurate to *what*?

Comment: All clock face designs are different. What I suggest you do is look at some examples. Use [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1920&bih=938&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=5Dz9WtDaM4jNgAaS05nABA&q=clock+face+roman+numerals&oq=clock+face+roman&gs_l=img.1.0.0l2j0i30k1l3j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l3.154702.155408.0.157433.6.6.0.0.0.0.175.736.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.img..1.5.733...0i67k1.0.XhbPiFdd-gU)

Comment: @BillyKerr I am interested in the mathematics behind the art

Comment: @Hector The mathematics? Can't you just use guides to divide the circle in 12 equal pieces and use that to place the                                                  numbers? I feel like you are making this way more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: It's simple arithmetic to divide a circle into 12.  For the hours, the angles are 360/12 = 30 degrees. For the minutes 360/60 - 6 degrees. There are different layouts for the numbers, some follow round the circle, others are just placed at the hour positions. There are no rules. Do what you want. Look at examples.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I agree that is simple mathematics. What isn't simple is to draw & place I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, XI, & XII around the circumference of a circle accurately. AS I have updated my question. Where does the mathematics come in when "looking at examples"?

Comment: @Hector Your question is a bit unclear. Have you applied to your fonts a sort of perspective in order to maintain a radial alignment? Or have you curved your fonts in order to follow the circumference? Without an example is difficult to give an answer. You are claiming for a formula that is related to aesthetics, and this is very difficult... Have you searched on the net for sundial images? They have interesting arrangement of roman numbers. I suggest you to re-formulate your question, which is interesting but too broad.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini, exactly that... I am looking for an aesthetics formula. I wanted to employ the COLVMNA·TRAIANI font.

Comment: There's no maths, the numbers simply are placed at the hour divisions. There is no such thing as an aesthetics formula. Do what you want. Use your eye to judge aesthetics.

Comment: You say "What isn't simple is to draw & place I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, XI, & XII around the circumference of a circle accurately" - but actually it is simple. Also you haven't even mentioned what software you are using. This question is too broad. It will just end up getting closed as all broad questions do.

Comment: I haven't mentioned software as I am not employing software. To categorise placing Roman numerals around a clock face as"too broad" seems harsh!

Comment: Well I haven't voted to close - but 3 have already.  I am just trying to make you aware that broad questions get closed. Don't accuse people here please. It's not nice.

Comment: @BillyKerr, please show me where I made an accusation?

Comment: OK start by editing your post to describe what tools you have the answer is totally different if you asking us how to do this with a ruler and protractor than with a computer. Its on topic but as it is not explaining what your problem is with accurate placement then you will not find many people willing to answer.

Comment: @Hector. I don't see difficult at technical level (with a vector editing software is really simple arrange the numbers and modify them), I suggest you to perform a little research and then edit your post adding pictures of your efforts, focusing on either a technical issue (e.g. "I'm not able to obtain this effect") or on a critique request based upon your results.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematics for a circular face with evenly spread numbers are fairly straight-forward...

Using the center as an origin point, merely place numbers at 30° intervals.

- 12 @ 360°/0°
- 1 @ 30°
- 2 @ 60°
- 3 @ 90°
- 4 @ 120°
- 5 @ 150°
- 6 @ 180°
- 7 @ 210°
- 8 @ 240°
- 9 @ 270°
- 10 @ 300°
- 11 @ 330°

For **minute** marks you place a tick at 6° intervals around the circle. Allowing the hour marks to take precedence when they overlap the minute marks.

Comment: I think OP would like to know whether the middle-of-box, center-of-gravity, left upper edge.... etc of the numerals should go on the lines you prescribed. Furthermore it's probable that OP would like to know on what radii to put said points (or define some "boundingbox/characters/convex hull touches circle"-rule) as the boxwidth is bound to vary wildly.

Comment: Well you apparently excelled at those mind reading classes which I failed @bukwyrm `:)` I can only based "what the OP wants" on what the OP has posted.